# Android - content of the adapter has changed?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I'm trying to get my endless list working but all the time I get IllegalStateException about modifying content of the adapter. I have totally no clue why it happens.

The error is pretty

```
IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131493058, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class ListNewsAdapter)]
```

Here is my AsyncTask:

```
public class ListDownloadNewAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, NewsArrayList> {
    private String mLastId = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ListNewsAdapter adapter = (ListNewsAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
        if (adapter != null && adapter.getCount() > 0) {
            mLastId = adapter.getItem(adapter.getCount() - 1).getId();
        }
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected NewsArrayList doInBackground(Void... params) {
        NewsArrayList downloadedNews = null;
        try {
            downloadedNews = JSONLoader.loadNews(getActivity(), mLastId);
        } catch (Exception ex) { }
        return downloadedNews;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(NewsArrayList result) {
        mLeftToDownload = result.getLeft();
        ListNewsAdapter adapter = (ListNewsAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new ListNewsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.news_list_row, result.getNewsArray(), NewsListFragment.this);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            adapter.addAll(result.getNewsArray());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            isLoading = false;
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

I was searching for any code snippet about endless listView, but most things I have found were with static or dynamically created - not downloaded.

So my question is... What have I missed here? Or what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is my Adapter class

```
public class ListNewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> {
private final ArrayList<News> news;
private final int newsRowResourceId;
private View progressView;
NewsListFragment fragment;

public ListNewsAdapter(Context context, int newsRowResourceId, ArrayList<News> news, NewsListFragment fragment) {
    super(context, newsRowResourceId, news);
    this.news = news;
    this.newsRowResourceId = newsRowResourceId;
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NewsListFragment.isLoading() ? news.size() + 1 : news.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewHolder holder;

    try {
        if (convertView == null || convertView.findViewById(R.id.title) != null || convertView == progressView) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(newsRowResourceId, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.news_list_item_image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (position < getCount()) {
            News newsRow = news.get(position);

            if (newsRow != null) {
                holder.title.setText(newsRow.getTitle().trim().replaceAll("[\n\r]", " "));
                holder.description.setText(newsRow.getDescription().trim().replaceAll("[\n\r]", " "));

                if (newsRow.getPhotoUrl() != null && !newsRow.getPhotoUrl().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                    Ion.with(holder.image).placeholder( R.drawable.icon ).load(newsRow.getPhotoUrl());
                } else {
                    holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
                }
            }
        }
        convertView.setClickable(true);
        convertView.setFocusable(true);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Main.instance.changeNewsFragment(news.get(position).getNewsUrl());
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        progressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_list_item, null);
        return progressView;
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView description;
    ImageView image;
}
}
```

EDIT: I thought about one more thing. I am launching that asynctask from OnScrollListener:

```
public abstract class InfiniteScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    private int bufferItemCount = 10;

    public InfiniteScrollListener(int bufferItemCount) {
        this.bufferItemCount = bufferItemCount;
    }

    public abstract void loadMore();

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if ((mLeftToDownload > 0) && !isLoading && ((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) >= (totalItemCount - bufferItemCount))) {
            Log.d("test", "from onScroll: " + mLeftToDownload + ", " + isLoading + ", " + (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) + ">=" + (totalItemCount - bufferItemCount));
            isLoading = true;
            loadMore();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_fragment, null);
    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_news);

    mLeftToDownload = -1;

    listView.setOnScrollListener(new InfiniteScrollListener(5) {
        @Override
        public void loadMore() {
            new ListDownloadNewAsyncTask().execute();
        }
    });
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);

    new ListDownloadNewAsyncTask().execute();

    return v;
}
```

And so I thought that it might be something with two tasks working on the same adapter. So I have modify last part of `if` statement in `onscroll` method and this reduced the amount of crashes but I still have some.

EDIT: Logcat for @Elltz

```
05-12 00:58:51.027    5108-5108/app.packg E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131493058, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class ListNewsAdapter)]
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1538)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4385)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:524)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is this list being loaded only once, or constantly getting new results?

Comment: @DroidChris: List is getting new results (getting few older news once user scroll to the bottom).

Comment: @iRaviiVooda: first set of items are put to adapter's constructor.

Comment: show your adapter class

Comment: I see no other explanation than some work on the background thread affecting the adapter. does the JsonLoader.loadNews() do that by any chance?

Comment: @appoll: I have added one more thing. About `loadNews()` method, there is nothing with adapter inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after analysing your code, this seems to be a working solution, try this:

1.Add this method to your adapter

```
public void addNewData(ArrayList<News> newData) {
    if(news != null) {
        news.addAll(newData);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

2.Replace `onPostExecute` with this

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(NewsArrayList result) {
    mLeftToDownload = result.getLeft();
    ListNewsAdapter adapter = (ListNewsAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new ListNewsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.news_list_row, result.getNewsArray(), NewsListFragment.this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        adapter.addNewData(result.getNewsArray());
        isLoading = false;
    }
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

Hope this will help

**EDIT** So apparently it didn't work, so the last resort is to change the adapter

```
public class ListNewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final ArrayList<News> news;
private View progressView;
NewsListFragment fragment;

LayoutInflater inflater;

public ListNewsAdapter(Context context, NewsListFragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(news == null)
         return 0;
    return NewsListFragment.isLoading() ? news.size() + 1 : news.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    try {
        if (convertView == null || convertView.findViewById(R.id.title) != null || convertView == progressView) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.news_list_item_image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (position < getCount()) {
            News newsRow = getItem(position);

            if (newsRow != null) {
                holder.title.setText(newsRow.getTitle().trim().replaceAll("[\n\r]", " "));
                holder.description.setText(newsRow.getDescription().trim().replaceAll("[\n\r]", " "));

                if (newsRow.getPhotoUrl() != null && !newsRow.getPhotoUrl().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                    Ion.with(holder.image).placeholder( R.drawable.icon ).load(newsRow.getPhotoUrl());
                } else {
                    holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
                }
            }
        }
        convertView.setClickable(true);
        convertView.setFocusable(true);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Main.instance.changeNewsFragment(news.get(position).getNewsUrl());
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        progressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_list_item, null);
        return progressView;
    }
}

@Override
public News getItem(int position) {
    return news.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView description;
    ImageView image;
}

public void addNewData(ArrayList<News> newData) {
    if(news == null) {
         news = new ArrayList<News>();
    }
    news.addAll(newData);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

and replace `onPostExecute`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(NewsArrayList result) {
    mLeftToDownload = result.getLeft();
    ListNewsAdapter adapter = (ListNewsAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new ListNewsAdapter(getActivity(), NewsListFragment.this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    adapter.addNewData(result.getNewsArray());
    isLoading = false;

    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

I hope i'm not missing anything I just wrote that by hand I don't have Eclipse on me.

Comment: Unfortunatelly nothing has changed. Maybe the reason was that ProgressView? I have turned it off and it looks like it works now...